# Scalar multiplication and standard matrix addition

Tags: vector-spaces

I am working on a problem, and I am asked to determine whether the given set and operations define a vector space, if not indicate which laws fail:
$$
V = \left\{ \left.
  \begin{pmatrix}
      a & b \\
      0 & a+b
  \end{pmatrix}
  \;\right|\;
  a,b \in \mathbb{R} \right\}
$$
with the standard matrix addition and scalar multiplication. I don't understand how to begin the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the notation $V=[ab;...\mid a,b\in R$ (for me $[a,b]$ is a Lie bracket).

Comment: Do you mean $[a\  b; 0\  a+b]$ to be the matrix with first row $(a,b)$ and second row $(0,a+b)$?

Comment: Yes Tobias, you are correct. I wasn't sure how to translate the rows here so I used the syntax from Matlab.

Comment: Ok. Note that it is not actually important to distinguish the rows here, so you might as well just consider these as $4$-tuples of the form $(a,b,0,a+b) $. Do you see how to do the problem then?